# Rename specific colum names in some data frames in a list of data frames with dplyr

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list `lst` of four data frames with some mistakes in their headings. What I need is to change selectively the names of the columns named `c` and `d` to `a` and `date_mmddyyy` to `date_ymd`. In my real list there are 66 data frames with different number of columns and different column names but here is a small example:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(V1 = seq(1:10), V2 = seq(11:20), V3 = c("01/22/2018", "01/23/2018", "01/24/2018", "01/25/2018", "01/26/2018", "01/27/2018", "01/28/2018", "01/29/2018", "01/30/2018", "01/31/2018"))
    df2 <- data.frame(V1 = seq(21:30), V2 = seq(31:40), V3 = c("01/22/2017", "01/23/2017", "01/24/2017", "01/25/2017", "01/26/2017", "01/27/2017", "01/28/2017", "01/29/2017", "01/30/2017", "01/31/2017"))
    df3 <- data.frame(V1 = seq(41:50), V2 = seq(51:60), V3 = c("01/22/2016", "01/23/2016", "01/24/2016", "01/25/2016", "01/26/2016", "01/27/2016", "01/28/2016", "01/29/2016", "01/30/2016", "01/31/2016"))
    df4 <- data.frame(V1 = seq(61:70), V2 = seq(71:80), V3 = c("01/22/2015", "01/23/2015", "01/24/2015", "01/25/2015", "01/26/2015", "01/27/2015", "01/28/2015", "01/29/2015", "01/30/2015", "01/31/2015"))
    
    lst <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
    
    headers <- list(c("c", "b", "date_mmddyyy"), c("d", "b", "date_mmddyyy"), c("a", "b", "date_mmddyyy"), c("a", "b", "date_mmddyyy"))

    lst <- lapply(seq(lst), function(i) {
      y <- lst[[i]]
      names(y) <- headers[[i]]
      return(y)
    })
```

I achieved the desired outcome with the following:

```
lst <- lapply(seq(lst), function(i) {
  y <- lst[[i]]
  names(y)[names(y) == "c"] <- "a"
  names(y)[names(y) == "d"] <- "a"
  names(y)[names(y) == "date_mmddyyy"] <- "date_ymd"
  return(y)
})
```

Nevertheless, I was wandering if there is a more concise way of doing it. More specifically I have tried with `dplyr` `rename()` function like this:

```
 lst <- lapply(seq(lst), function(i) {
  y <- lst[[i]]
  y <- rename(y, a = c, a = d, date_ymd = date_mmddyyy)
  return(y)
})
```

Outcome:

```
Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist.
x Column `c` doesn't exist.
```

It seems though that `rename()` returns error once it reaches a data frame that it does not contain any of the specified column names to be changed. Is there workaround this limitation of `rename()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `purrr`, `dplyr` and `stringr` solution could be:

```
map(.x = lst,
    ~ .x %>%
     rename_all(~ str_replace_all(., c("\\bc\\b" = "a", 
                                       "\\bd\\b" = "a", 
                                       "\\bdate_mmddyyy\\b" = "date_ymd"))))


[[1]]
    a  b   date_ymd
1   1  1 01/22/2018
2   2  2 01/23/2018
3   3  3 01/24/2018
4   4  4 01/25/2018
5   5  5 01/26/2018
6   6  6 01/27/2018
7   7  7 01/28/2018
8   8  8 01/29/2018
9   9  9 01/30/2018
10 10 10 01/31/2018

[[2]]
    a  b   date_ymd
1   1  1 01/22/2017
2   2  2 01/23/2017
3   3  3 01/24/2017
4   4  4 01/25/2017
5   5  5 01/26/2017
6   6  6 01/27/2017
7   7  7 01/28/2017
8   8  8 01/29/2017
9   9  9 01/30/2017
10 10 10 01/31/2017

[[3]]
    a  b   date_ymd
1   1  1 01/22/2016
2   2  2 01/23/2016
3   3  3 01/24/2016
4   4  4 01/25/2016
5   5  5 01/26/2016
6   6  6 01/27/2016
7   7  7 01/28/2016
8   8  8 01/29/2016
9   9  9 01/30/2016
10 10 10 01/31/2016

[[4]]
    a  b   date_ymd
1   1  1 01/22/2015
2   2  2 01/23/2015
3   3  3 01/24/2015
4   4  4 01/25/2015
5   5  5 01/26/2015
6   6  6 01/27/2015
7   7  7 01/28/2015
8   8  8 01/29/2015
9   9  9 01/30/2015
10 10 10 01/31/2015
```